# Making equal-sized divs with white-space: nowrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a series of divs in a single row, each of them equal width, with the width being the length of the longest div. In other words, if I have this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Goodbye</div>
  <div>Some really long text</div>
  <div>More text</div>
</div>
```

I want all the text on one line (so `white-space: nowrap`), with each div being the length of the longest one, which would be "Some really long text" in this case.

My approach has been to use inline-flex, like the following:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This approach doesn't work since my divs are not equal sized. *However*, if I remove `white-space: nowrap`, then my divs are equal sized, but now the text is wrapped.

This is the Codepen of both versions: https://codepen.io/unpossible/pen/xjxKBM

So is there anyway to combine the no-wrapping of the first attempt and the equal sized divs of the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use grid layout instead of flex change wrapper to `inline-grid`

you can find more about it here [CSS Grid Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

and check this [codepen for your answer](https://codepen.io/adamragheb/pen/qYBBVE)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set **[`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)** to `0`.
Essentially, you're just looking for `flex: 1 0 25%` instead of `flex: 1 1 25%`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Goodbye</div>
  <div>Some really long text</div>
  <div>More text</div>
</div>
```